# How to get certain letters of an argument Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So I am making a mute command and I would like to know how to get certain letters of an argument for example if the user enters the command **=mute <user> 1d** I would like to get the letter 'd' from the 2nd argument, I tried to achieve this by using

```
args[1].charAt(1)
```

but that did not work for some reason, I also tried using

```
args[1].toString().charAt(1)
```

but that didn't work either, so I tried to search online for a fix, but I couldn't really find one that worked for me, if you do know how to do this, please let me know, if you do not understand my question let me know and I will try to explain it better for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String#split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to divide up the string into an array of substrings (each substring being the individual characters) and use [Array#pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the last character.

```
const timeArg = args.pop(); // Simply returns last element of array "args"
const timeChar = timeArg.split('').pop();
```